# Can I add the filename as a tag to the image on Lightroom when exporting

Tags: lightroom, metadata, tagging, keywords

Is there a way to add the filename as a keyword tag to the files being exported on Lightroom?

I'm using LR 4.1, just in case.

The thing is that after exporting, the files are renamed. Sometimes I need to go back to Lightroom and re-export that same image and it's hard to find...   if the original filename was added as a keyword tag, that wouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't. But what you can do is to export using file name and the capture date. That should help you to locate your photo later. To do this, in the export dialog under File Naming section, choose **Date - Filename** setting.

Comment: Yes, that I know..  But files get renamed, which is why I wanted the filename as a tag.   Do you know of a LR plugin or external tool that does this?

Comment: @Joao there isn't, I'm sorry but sometimes the answer is simply No. I wouldn't claim though that I know all the plugins, but I know alot and I didn't come across any plugin that does what you want, also I searched for it with no results.